# How to properly retrieving a php array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the variables: error, armount_payout, this.result1, this.result2, this.result3 from a ajax call, this is the code i have so far but it returns an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:25_
.parseJSON jquery.js:25
Game.restart slots.js:188
(anonymous function) slots.js:127
_.event.dispatch jquery.js:25
q.handle jquery.js:24
```

this is my php code:

```
    $arr = array(
        0=>$payout_amount,
        1=>$error,
        2 => $num1win,
        3=> $num2win,
        4=> $num3win
    );
echo json_encode($arr);
```

and my jquery code:

```
    data=$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../php/runslotsgame.php",
        data: "address=" + address,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            error = dataArray [0];
            armount_payout = dataArray [1];
            this.result1=dataArray [2];
            this.result2=dataArray [3];   
            this.result3=dataArray [4]; 
    console.log("yay");
```

also the "yay" does not apear in my console

does anyone see what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add your Content-Type=application/json header in your ajax response:

```
Content-Type = application/json
```

Also, not sure which version of jQuery you're using, but you need to check the callback, since .ajax() is an async function.

```
$.post(url,{address:address},function(data){
    var dataArray = data;
    //where you need to use your data array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit your JSON-making URL directly with your browser and inspect the output. Your error message suggests the JSON is invalid.

You can use a [JSON validator](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+validator&oq=json+vali&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.1549j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) to check it for problems.